# Hadoop features when installed on windows using virtual box

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

Do I get less features or functions of hadoop env. when installed on windows machine using virtual box? Is is good to have this sort of hadoop  installation for beginners practice? or What is the difference when hadoop in installed on linux machine vs installation on virtual box on a windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can have fully distributed cluster on your windows machine using multiple nodes in the virtual box .  However for beginners I will recommend you set up a single node cluster and do the practice. There is no thing as such that you will get less features . You will be running pseudo distributed mode of hadoop . All the daemons will be running.  Only thing is that since you have single windows machine with limited storage/ram, you cant test the cluster with huge amounts of data. Hope this helps.

Comment: if I install hadoop on single ubuntu machine then also this limitation will stay.I believe.Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Thats correct. But for beginners or even hadoop developers ,in project they do their testing with a single machine only. Run your programs with sample of data to test the logic.